# Subprocess not capturing the output of stdout storing it inside a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried the below code to capture the output from screen using the sub-process, but its not doing what I intended to do.

```
#!/tools/bin/python

import subprocess

result = subprocess.check_output("echo $USERNAME", shell=True)
print result
```

expected output is:

```
vimo 
vimo
```

i.e. one for the echo process and one for printing the result output. 
But what I see is

```
vimo
```

But when I try to print the result output, its always empty.

What am I missing in the above puzzle !! Help out !!

Comment: the parent process captures child's stdout. So the result is quite expected

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh ! sorry.. got confused and thought it will be printing two outputs.. but then I understood the value which is stored in the variable is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you goes some greatly stripped (and altered for privacy reasons) raw *dummy*  piece of code, grabbing both stdin and stdout from external script output.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = ['echo', 'foo']

proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
comm = proc.communicate()

if proc.returncode != 0:
    # code to handle / parse stderr (comm[1])
    raise RuntimeError(
        '\'%s\': command has failed (%d):\n%s'
        % ('some value', proc.returncode, comm[1]))

for line in comm[0].split('\n'):
    if line.find('Wrote:') == 0:
        # some code to parse stdout
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python >= 3.7 (tested with Python 3.9)

```py
r=subprocess.run(['echo','$XDG_DATA_HOME'],capture_output=True,shell=True)
assert r.stdout.find(b'share')>0 # ERROR
r=subprocess.run('echo $XDG_DATA_HOME',capture_output=True,shell=True)
assert r.stdout.find(b'share')>0 # OK
```